# Click button (toggle) to move in and out of web page a couple of words

Tags: jquery, html, css, button, toggle

1 word from left and the other word from right, both after clicking the button should meet on the same line.

I tried and re-tried the code but I dont understand what I did wrong.
The problem is inside the **footer** element I suppose.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('#slider').toggleClass('open');

})
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

@charset "utf-8";
 html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
/* fine reset */

.wrap {
  width: 100%;
}
/*footer in basso*/

#headertop {
  z-index: 30;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #676666;
}
/*animazione "michele caddeo" in footer*/

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-top: 3px solid #676666;
}
#slider {
  background: gray;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  left: -520px;
}
.open {
  left: 0px !important;
}
.transition {
  -webkit-transition: left 0.3s ease-out;
  /* Chrome 1-25, Safari 3.2+ */
  -moz-transition: left 0.3s ease-out;
  /* Firefox 4-15 */
  -o-transition: left 0.3s ease-out;
  /* Opera 10.50–12.00 */
  transition: left 0.3s ease-out;
  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */
}
/*container per il video*/

.floatleft {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #1F221E;
  height: 500px;
}
/*container a destra*/

.floatright {
  float: right;
  background-color: #B14446;
  height: 500px;
  width: 50%;
}
/*Video*/

#bg {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  top: 135px;
  left: 10px;
  padding: 3%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>cad</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="cad.css" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="animazionejs/cad.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript "></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="headertop "></div>
  <div class="wrap ">
    <div class="floatleft ">
      <video id="bg " src="images/filmato.mp4 " preload="auto " autoplay loop muted></video>
    </div>
    <div class="floatright "></div>
    <div style="clear: both; ">
    </div>

    <div id="footer ">
      <button>MICHELE CADDEO</button>
      <div id="slider " class="transition "></div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey, could you set up a Fiddle on http://www.jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Sure. here is the link for JSFIDDLE.NET http://jsfiddle.net/WDmichele/hbbvy9bp/

Comment: Can you explain your problem a little more in detail. What exactly do you mean by one word from the left and one word from the right? Where are these words coming from?